# Copying text box content to decimal in sql SQL via asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Hi I am trying to take the amount entered in a text box and save that to a sql database in decimal format. The field in the table is set as decimal 7,2

The amount a user inputs is save to the table. However it rounds the decimal amount. eg. 10.55 saved as 11.00 & 10.45 saved as 10.00

I'm using visual studio 2010 and vb.net

This is the code I'm using to write the content to the database. Any help would be appreciated.

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("customer_contribution", Convert.ToDecimal(CType(Me.FormView1.FindControl("CustomerContributionTextbox"), TextBox).Text))
```

I've also tried it without the Decimal conversion and end up with the same results.

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("customer_contribution", customer_contribution)
```

Comment: Are the correct values being sent to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Use @ symbol before parameter name. and if you want to specify the parameter's sqldbtype then use the properties of command parameter as per equivalent to decimal type.

Check this:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_contribution",
```

Follow this [Configuring Parameters and Parameter Data Types (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx)

```
 ' Add the input parameter and set its properties.
        Dim parameter As New SqlParameter()
        parameter.ParameterName = "@Price"
        parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        parameter.Value = categoryName

        ' Add the parameter to the Parameters collection.
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
```